# Find Information On This Component Of Fire Alarm

Tags: arduino, components

I have been trying to search for information on the component of a fire alarm that sounds the siren. My goal is to remove the siren and use the power and ground to connect to an arduino. I want the arduino to be alerted instead of sounding the alarm. The component has 3 prongs that are soldered into the board and I cannot figure out what each one does. Pictures are below:

Note: No this alarm will not be used as a normal fire alarm in a life or death situation.

[image: top of board]

[image: bottom of board]

Comment: Correct it is S2. I will get the other info soon.

Comment: I will get the photo replaced. I do not know the function for LED1. It was always empty. What number do I use on the DIP-16 IC? There are 3 numbers: A5366CAT, 1428824R, INDO.

Comment: No need, I think! The datasheet knows all! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A5366: Photoelectric Smoke Detector with Interconnect and Timer

http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A5366-Datasheet.ashx

pin 7 is I/O Pin : A connection at this pin allows multiple smoke detectors to be
interconnected. If any single unit detects smoke, its I/O pin is
driven high, and all connected units will sound their associated
horns.

The above data sheet has a nice typical circuit. Likely just what you have there.
The Horn appears to be a 3 pin Piezo. Where its feed back and pulsing will not be as easy, as just monitoring pin 7 of the chip.

Be-warned: this chip runs directly off of battery, up to 15V. Typically 9V battery. So the output of the IO will be that to. So it would be best to drive a resistor divider or clamping diode or something to ensure it does not exceed the VCC of the Arduino.

here is an example circuit to protect against the higher voltage of the A5366.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp757C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 is optional. [BAV99](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BA/BAV99.pdf) is a nice little SOT23 that can do this.

Comment: Yeah, what HE said.

Comment: ha :) thank you both. I'll check an answer after I have time to test it out.

Comment: Why was this down voted? Is something incorrect?

Comment: So you just simply added a 10K resistor to lower voltage correct?

Comment: D1 prevents the voltage at AVRinput exceeding AVRvcc, likewise D2 prevents it from going below the AVR's ground. The difference is dissipated across the 10K. Choose a R of your liking. This technique is used to protect most things. Most all chips have these diodes on all pins. But they are only strong enough to take minor static spikes. Hence in this case it is prudent to add stronger one and a resistor to absorb the diff. (not sure why someone down ticked it.)

Comment: "Why was this down voted? Is something incorrect?" - I spent the initial time with the OP (requesting the IC part number that this answer is based on, for example). When **I'd** finally gotten enough information to finalize my answer, this copy-and-paste showed up 8 minutes later and was accepted. I'm offended that my time was worth nothing to both @rys and mpflaga, so I down-voted it. Sometime yesterday, non-duplicate information was added.

Comment: Lol. That doesn't make the answer wrong. Makes you feel good though huh? This was worded nicely and had a very critical warning (was there since the original answer) about voltage or I probably would have fried something. I also up voted your answer. But since I guess you're not worth my time according to you, so let me remove that as well.

Answer (score 3):

With the IC part number, I was able to find this for you:
http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/218677/SENSITRON/A5366CA-T.html

The "typical application diagram" should be able to help you considerably, even if I am not.

Pin 7 is I/O interconnect:
When driven high by the Arduino, the alarm will sound. When read by the Arduino, a HIGH signal indicates the alarm is going off.

Pin 11 is LED output and flashes to indicate the current status:
Standby - Every 43s
Local Smoke - Every 0.5s
Remote Alarm - No pulses
Test Mode - Every 0.5s
Timer Mode - Every 10s

You should certainly be able to detect those with an Arduino.

Comment: Wow, that is very helpful. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Pin 7 is your best bet; it is used to make multiple detectors all go off together when any one of them goes off. I suspect that pin is routed to CONN1.

Comment: You got lucky, I up voted but can't down vote yet lol.

Comment: You can up-vote again to remove it